# Mathematica Generate conditions giving a different answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have defined a functions F(q) as shown in the image and want to integrate it over q from -infinity to infinity by taking some assumptions. I did it once with Generate conditions-> False and once without it. It gives me totally different answers. Note that it did not give me any conditions when I did not use it. What can be the reason[image]

Comment: It's difficult for others to help you if you don't provide code in text form that can be easily copied.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Mathematica Version 8.0, there are no problems.

(Maybe you have some predefinitions. Copy my code and do again.)

```
F[q_] = -((q^4 vF^4 vq^2)/((q^2 vh^2 + wm^2)^2 \[Beta]^2 (I wm - 
            q vF \[Nu]) (-I wm + q vF \[Nu])))

(*     -((q^4 vF^4 vq^2)/((q^2 vh^2 + wm^2)^2 \[Beta]^2 (I wm - 
        q vF \[Nu]) (-I wm + q vF \[Nu])))     *)

Integrate[F[q], {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    Assumptions -> {vh > 0, wm^2 > 0, 
      vF > 0, \[Nu]^2 == 1, \[Nu]p^2 == 1, 
      vq^2 > 0, \[Beta] > 0}] // FullSimplify

(*     ConditionalExpression[(\[Pi] vF^4 (vF + 3 vh) vq^2)/(
          2 vh^3 (vF + vh)^3 wm \[Beta]^2), \[Nu] == 
          1 && (\[Nu]p == -1 || \[Nu]p == 1) && wm > 0]     *)

Integrate[F[q], {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    Assumptions -> {vh > 0, wm^2 > 0, 
       vF > 0, \[Nu]^2 == 1, \[Nu]p^2 == 1, vq^2 > 0, \[Beta] > 0}, 
       GenerateConditions -> False] // FullSimplify

(*   (\[Pi] vF^4 (vF + 3 vh) vq^2)/(2 vh^3 (vF + vh)^3 \[Beta]^2 Abs[wm])   *)
```